# Add ePub automatically to stores

Tags: automation, publishing, epub, ibooks

does anyone know if there are any API's out there that allow you to automatically add published ePub's to all the major eBook stores like the iBookStore, Amazon Kindle or Kobo eBooks?

I can find loads of info on creating ePubs and adding them manually to the stores, but we would like to make the entire process automated so that anyone in our company can easily upload a pdf, some images and some text and it ends up live on the bookstores without any manual interference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think automated submission is possible for any of the stores, let alone all of them. Certainly for Apple you need to use their custom software to submit the ePub; Amazon requires you to use their web form. Neither is scriptable as far as I'm aware (although you could probably export the metadata to an iTunes-Publisher-ready format).